# How to calculate percentage change within a partition? - R

Tags: r, partition, calculated-field

I have a series of performance metrics and want to calculate the percentage change from the previous row but within a defined partition, as such:

```
   index metric percent_change
   A     10     0.0
   A     20     1.0
   A     10     -.50
   A     5      -.50
   B     10     0
   B     5      -.50
   B     10     1.00
```

How can I accomplish this in R?

Comment: also `with(df1, ave(metric, index, FUN = function(x) c(0, (tail(x, -1) - head(x, -1)) / head(x, -1))))`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'index', we subtract the 'fill' from the lag of 'fill' and divide by it and assign (`:=`) the result to the create the 'percent_change'.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
setDT(df1)[, percent_change := {tmp <- shift(metric, fill=metric[1L])
                 (metric-tmp)/tmp} , by =  index]
df1
#   index metric percent_change
#1:     A     10            0.0
#2:     A     20            1.0
#3:     A     10           -0.5
#4:     A      5           -0.5
#5:     B     10            0.0
#6:     B      5           -0.5
#7:     B     10            1.0
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(index) %>%
     mutate(percent_change = (metric- lag(metric, default=metric[1L]))/lag(metric, default=metric[1L]))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(index = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), 
metric = c(10L, 20L, 10L, 5L, 10L, 5L, 10L)), .Names = c("index", 
"metric"), 
 row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative using the base package:

```
df1$percent_change <- unlist(
tapply(df1$metric, df1$index, function(x) c(0, x[-1]/x[1]-1) )
)
```

Or a very similar to the one proposed by rawr

```
df1$percent_change <- ave(df1$metric, df1$index, FUN=function(x) c(0,x[-1]/x[1]-1))
```

Output:

```
  index metric percent_change
1     A     10            0.0
2     A     20            1.0
3     A     10            0.0
4     A      5           -0.5
5     B     10            0.0
6     B      5           -0.5
7     B     10            0.0
```